# Position of Actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I had a problem with position of actor

Here is actor class:

```
public class Test extends Actor {
  Sprite sprite;
  Vector2 actorPosition;

  public Test() {
    Texture t = new Texture("img.png");
    sprite = new Sprite(t);
    sprite.setSize(t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
    actorPosition = new Vector2();

    // set the size and position of actor
    setSize(sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());
    setPosition(actorPosition.x, actorPosition.y);

    debug();
  }

  public void setActorPosition(Vector2 actorPosition) {
    this.actorPosition = actorPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.draw(sprite, actorPosition.x, actorPosition.y, getWidth(), getHeight());
  }
}
```

When I call the `setActorPosition` method, the sprite drawing in a specific position is fine but the actor position is still at `(0, 0)`.

I want the actor and sprite to be draw at the same position using this method because I want to control this position in another class.

How can I do this?

Comment: add a code example ho you are using your actor and render method from the screen with stage that has th actor

Comment: l make a stage and add test to it but before I call setActorPosition method
drawing of sprite goes as I want but by calling debug the bounds are at 0,0

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Actor's position using:

```
setX(float x);
setY(float y);
```

You could do it like this:

```
public void setActorPosition(Vector2 actorPosition) {
    this.actorPosition = actorPosition;
    setX(actorPosition.x);
    setY(actorPosition.y);
}
```